# Running into problems hosting a website on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm starting to learn more on the back-end scale of programming.

Recently I started up Heroku for the second or third time. This time I actually installed the Git update to my Mac and installed Heroku in the terminal.

I wanted to upload a static HTML site with the Sinatra gem. Everything worked out fine inside the terminal, though I added Sinatra after I got everything working and the file with the site hooked up to Heroku. In my logs I did see that I was missing the Sinatra gem, so I installed it.

My site contains both the proper `app.rb` and `config.ru` files. 
I have nothing showing up online though, just a blank screen!

Contacting Heroku on this problem has been very difficult: I get a response every day, and on every day I respond with a question to the answer that didn't help me at all.

**Edit:**

Here is my Heroku log file:

```
2011-05-18T00:25:20+00:00 app[web.1]: 71.198.0.51 - - [17/May/2011 17:25:20] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0008
2011-05-18T00:25:20+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=313
2011-05-18T00:25:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 71.198.0.51 - - [17/May/2011 17:25:26] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0008
2011-05-18T00:25:26+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms bytes=313
2011-05-17T18:25:51-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-05-17T18:26:01-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-05-18T01:26:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-18T01:26:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-18T01:26:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-05-17T20:12:46-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-05-17T20:12:47-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-18T03:12:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 40055 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-05-18T03:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-05-18T03:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-18T03:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:40055, CTRL+C to stop
2011-05-18T03:12:50+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=9954ms service=6ms bytes=565
2011-05-18T03:12:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 70.91.206.114 - - [17/May/2011 20:12:50] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0012
2011-05-18T03:12:50+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/style.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=269
2011-05-17T20:12:50-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-18T03:12:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 70.91.206.114 - - [17/May/2011 20:12:51] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0008
2011-05-18T03:12:51+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms bytes=313
2011-05-18T03:13:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms bytes=565
2011-05-18T03:13:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 70.91.206.114 - - [17/May/2011 20:13:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 0.0011
2011-05-18T03:13:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=313
2011-05-18T03:13:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 70.91.206.114 - - [17/May/2011 20:13:05] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0007
2011-05-18T03:57:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 172.18.33.56, 58.96.134.66 - - [17/May/2011 20:57:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 0.0007
2011-05-18T03:57:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms bytes=565
2011-05-18T03:57:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 172.18.33.56, 58.96.134.66 - - [17/May/2011 20:57:05] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0007
2011-05-18T03:57:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/style.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=269
2011-05-18T03:57:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 172.18.33.56, 58.96.134.66 - - [17/May/2011 20:57:08] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0008
2011-05-17T21:58:27-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-05-18T04:58:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-18T04:58:30+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-18T04:58:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-05-17T21:58:33-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-05-17T23:11:58-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-05-17T23:11:58-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-18T06:12:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 40091 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-05-18T06:12:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-05-18T06:12:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-18T06:12:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:40091, CTRL+C to stop
2011-05-18T06:12:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 183.97.156.226 - - [17/May/2011 23:12:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 0.0017
2011-05-18T06:12:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=3209ms service=5ms bytes=565
2011-05-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 183.97.156.226 - - [17/May/2011 23:12:03] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0019
2011-05-17T23:12:08-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-18T00:13:13-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-05-18T00:13:16-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-05-18T07:13:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-18T07:13:16+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-18T07:13:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-05-18T01:54:21-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-05-18T01:54:21-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-18T08:54:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 59491 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-05-18T08:54:24+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-05-18T08:54:24+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-18T08:54:24+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:59491, CTRL+C to stop
2011-05-18T01:54:28-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=6943ms service=6ms bytes=565
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 62.244.82.72 - - [18/May/2011 01:54:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 0.0018
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/style.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=269
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 62.244.82.72 - - [18/May/2011 01:54:28] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0014
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 62.244.82.72 - - [18/May/2011 01:54:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0008
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1ms bytes=313
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms bytes=313
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 62.244.82.72 - - [18/May/2011 01:54:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0008
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 62.244.82.72 - - [18/May/2011 01:54:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0008
2011-05-18T08:54:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1ms bytes=313
2011-05-18T02:55:23-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-05-18T02:55:33-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-05-18T09:55:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-18T09:55:34+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-18T09:55:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-05-18T07:23:10-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-18T14:23:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 20560 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-05-18T14:23:13+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-05-18T14:23:13+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-18T14:23:13+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:20560, CTRL+C to stop
2011-05-18T07:23:13-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-18T14:23:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 12.183.19.10 - - [18/May/2011 07:23:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 0.0018
2011-05-18T14:23:14+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms bytes=565
2011-05-18T14:23:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 12.183.19.10 - - [18/May/2011 07:23:14] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0015
2011-05-18T14:23:14+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/style.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=269
2011-05-18T14:23:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 12.183.19.10 - - [18/May/2011 07:23:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0009
2011-05-18T14:23:14+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=313
2011-05-18T08:24:03-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-05-18T08:24:07-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-05-18T15:24:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-05-18T15:24:07+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-18T17:34:27-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-05-18T17:34:28-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-19T00:34:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 57621 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-05-18T17:34:31-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-19T00:34:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms bytes=565
2011-05-19T00:34:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 97.83.58.74 - - [18/May/2011 17:34:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 0.0016
2011-05-19T00:34:32+00:00 app[web.1]: 97.83.58.74 - - [18/May/2011 17:34:32] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0011
2011-05-19T00:34:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/style.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=269
2011-05-19T00:34:34+00:00 heroku[router]: GET pxlc.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms bytes=313
2011-05-19T00:34:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 97.83.58.74 - - [18/May/2011 17:34:34] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0007
2011-05-18T18:35:48-07:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-05-18T18:35:51-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
```

Comment: i think this question should be migrated to http://serverfault.com/ or webmasters (and using paragraphs to make the text more readable is a good idea, and including config files or links to pastebin will help improve the chance of someone answering)

Answer (score 1):

Can you edit your question to include the contents of your Heroku log file.

```
heroku logs -n 500 --app your_app_name
```

The url is http://pxlc.heroku.com, note the lack of www. It is returning the following HTML file

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
   <head> 
      <title></title> 
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> 
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
   </body> 
</html>
```